# Parallel jobs in Ant using a list

Tags: list, ant, parallel-processing, ant-contrib

I'm trying to run parallel tasks on Ant.
User provide a list of server (`-Drhosts="rhost1,rhost2,..."`) and the system should start the same target only using a different host each time.
`<ac:for>` and `<ac:foreach>` only support `<sequential>`, not `<parallel>`

Any idea?

Answer (score 9):

It supports parallel running by specifying an property.

Parameters of Ant-contrib's `<for>` task:

> parallel
>   If true, all iterations of the nested  will execute in parallel. Defaults to false, which forces sequential execution of the iterations. It is up to the caller to ensure that parallel execution is safe.
>
> threadCount
>   The maximum number of allowable threads when executing in parallel.

So if you can set `parallel="true"`. Please note that there is nothing to do with the nested `<sequential>` element, because the tasks inside `<sequential>` are still executed sequentially; by setting `parallel` parameter, you tell `<for>` tasks to execute multiple `<sequential>`s at the same time -- how many? It depends on the number of elements in your list, as well as the value of `threadCount`.

Please check

http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html

to see all the parameters.

---

And for `<foreach>` task, it executes the specified target for each element in your list, or each file in the nested fileset. You can also use `parallel` property to make the execution parallel.

Check

http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/foreach.html

Comment: @user1633264 At least read the table of properties of the task. Also, plz click accept if this is the answer that helps you to sovle your problem.

Comment: Would be nice if you extend your answer with the information, how it should look like if the "list" contains names of other targets defined in build.xml. I found it only in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46299109/4807875 that it should be <antcall target="@{list_param}"/>.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample piece of code:

```
 <for list="some_list" param="list_param" delimiter="any_delimiter" parallel="true">
     <sequential>
        ...         
     </sequential>
 </for>
```